# Google analytics for flex mobile show no data

Tags: apache-flex, google-analytics, flex-mobile

I added Google Analytics for my mobile application, but it's been 12 days and I see NO data there.

I checked the code and it seems fine, no exceptions or anything like that.
Here is the code I am using:

```
import com.google.analytics.GATracker;
import com.google.analytics.AnalyticsTracker;

...

tracker = new GATracker( this, "(My Google Tracking Code)", "AS3", false );
tracker.trackPageview("myapp/postinit");
tracker.trackEvent("myapp","Start","User started playing");
```

If it helps, I tried Flurry - but same results - no data is being reported....

Any ideas ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved - 
After talking to Google's product manager:

When you register a new analytics site/mobile in Google Analytics, 
You need to register is as a **WEBSITE** rather than a mobile app.

This solves the problem - verified, both for track events and track web pages.

Koby.